# Executing commands through shell-command (what is the PATH used)?

Tags: shell-command

If I do:

```lisp
  (getenv "PATH")
```

I get a list of colon-separated directories, including:

```
  /Users/michaeln/Library/Haskell/bin
```

If I look at the `exec-path` variable, I see a list including the same directory.  If I do:

```lisp
  (shell-command "echo $PATH")
```

I get a list of colon-separated directories including the same `Haskell/bin` directory as above.  There is an executable `pandoc` in that directory.  And yet, if I do:

```lisp
  (shell-command "pandoc")
```

I get in response:

```
  /bin/bash: pandoc: command not found
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Try adding the path of the folder where `pandoc` is located to your `exec-path`:  http://emacswiki.org/emacs/ExecPath

Comment: are you able to run `pandoc`  from `bash` shell prompt?

Comment: @lawlist I have; as above "If I look at the `exec-path` variable...".

Comment: @MadhavanKumar Yes.  If I run `M-x shell` and type `pandoc --version`, or if I run my usual shell within Terminal.app.

Comment: `exec-path` is only relevant to binaries Emacs wants to run. In this instance Emacs is running a shell (and the shell is running pandoc), so I believe there's no particular reason in this case for pandoc to be accessible from `exec-path`.

Comment: This looks weird to me. What does `which pandoc` report from the shell?

Comment: What if your shell profile overwrites `PATH` variable?

Comment: where/how are you adding your `../Haskell/bin` directory to your path? my guess is that it is getting added dynamically for interactive shells, which `(shell-command)` is not considered by default. does it work if you set the following: `(setq shell-command-switch "-ic")`?

Comment: @waymondo Yes, that is the key. I'm fairly certain that Emacs inherits the `PATH` from the shell where it's run. If, for instance, op has `export PATH=$PATH:~/Haskell/bin` in his `.bashrc`, but runs Emacs from, say, a desktop icon, it may not inherit the proper path.

Comment: But notice that `(getenv "PATH")` returns the directory I want.  Nonetheless, I think @waymondo is right: the `Haskell/bin` directory is added interactively, not for non-interactive shells.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you are adding your Haskell bin to your `PATH` in a `.bashrc` or similar dotfile, this file only gets loaded when running an "interactive" shell. This happens when running `M-x shell` but not when running `M-!` / `(shell-command)`, as there is no prompt. You can adjust the option flags that are sent to `(shell-command)` by adjusting `shell-command-switch` to instruct it to act interactively and load your shell dotfile with:

```
(setq shell-command-switch "-ic")
```

Comment: Curiously, something about my non-interactive bash setup must be setting my `PATH` rather than extending it: otherwise, surely the non-interactive shell would inherit the `PATH` variable that `emacs` has in its own environment.

Comment: Now, without changing any of my config files, I can't even reproduce the behaviour.  I have rebooted the relevant machine because it just upgraded OS X version.  I think the comment about interactive *vs* non-interactive shells is still very valuable though.  Thanks!